# How can I use absolute imports with storybook and Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, storybook

In my `.storybook/main.js` file, I have:

```
 webpackFinal: async (config) => {
     config.resolve.modules = [
       ...(config.resolve.modules || []),
       path.resolve(__dirname),
     ];

     return config;
   },
```

But when I run my storybook, I get an error:

```
resolve 'components/Common/Button' in '/myprojectpath/pages'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /myprojectpath/package.json (relative path: ./pages)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /myprojectpath/pages/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /myprojectpath/node_modules
```

Not sure what's happening. When I run the Next.js project, it loads fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the setting absolute path issue: [github issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11639)

Most likely, will be solved with

```
path.resolve(__dirname, ".."), "node_modules"]
```

or

```
path.resolve(__dirname, "../src"), "node_modules"]
```